# From a list of objects, get several properties of the same (or nullable) type into a distinct list

Tags: c#, linq

In a `List` of objects with many properties, each object has three different properties, RegionID, DistrictID, and SuburbID, that I want to extract from each object and put into a single distinct list. RegionID is of type `long`, and DistrictID and SuburbID are of type `long?`. I want the quickest and easiest way to extract these three properties into a single distinct list of type `long?`.

The following works but seems inelegant:

```
List<long> regionIDsLong = objectList.Select(x => x.RegionID).ToList(); 

List<long?> regionIDs = regionIDsLong.Cast<long?>().ToList();

List<long?> districtIDs = objectList.Select(x => x.DistrictID).ToList();

List<long?> suburbIDs = objectList.Select(x => x.SuburbID).ToList();

List<long?> locationIDs = regionIDs.Concat(districtIDs).Concat(suburbIDs).Distinct().ToList();
```

Can I do this with a single `Select` or `SelectMany` statement, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, and is a bit shorter. It creates an array for each instance of the class, then flattens them out and converts the distinct values to a list.

```
List<long?> locationIds = objectList.Select(x => new[] { x.RegionID, x.DistrictID, x.SuburbID })
                                    .SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect elegance.